# Highcharts change tooltip / label value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to change the tooltip in the label representing the X value for another one based on it?

In my case, I have dates as values but I'm only showing the number of the month in the X axis.
When moving the mouse over the dots I would like to see the full date.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to build a function in the `formatter` to create or map the date based on the x value - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: refer this...http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/tooltip/formatter/

Comment: If you have datetime axis, you should be able to use xDateFormat for formating your date in tooltip: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.xDateFormat

Comment: you can use formatter to format tooltip. you can find API detail and demo here. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter